# TypeError: message.reactions.fetch is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
  client.on('messageCreate', async(message) => {
    if (message.author.bot)return
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if(message.content.startsWith('!reroll')){
          if(!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
                const content = args.join(' ');
                let winner = message.reactions.fetch(content).cache.get("").users.cache.filter((users) => !users.bot).random(winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1));
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setDescription(`${winner}`);
                  message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
                message.delete({timeout: 1500}).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    })
```

I tried to make a giveaway reroll command but I got this error.

```
TypeError: message.reactions.fetch is not a function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no `reactions.fetch()` method. `message.reactions` returns a [`ReactionManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ReactionManager) so you can use its `cache` like this:

```js
let winner = message.reactions.cache
  .get('')
  .users.cache.filter((user) => !user.bot)
  .random(winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1));
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with `args.join(' ')` though.

Comment: If you, for some reason, really want to make sure you have an updated cache for that message you can `message.fetch()` and then `message.reactions.cache` etc.

Comment: i want to reroll specific embed